# 7-ZIP can't open pictures in Windows default photo viewer (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip, windows-photo-viewer

I updated 7-ZIP to the latest version 9.2, but when I try to open e.g. jpg from zip archive I always get a message "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either this picture is deleted, or it's in a location that isn't available."

At the same time most other picture viewers can't open pictures from 7-zip archive. Could anybody "teach" Windows Photo Viewer how to work with 7-zip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, it is a bug in 7-Zip. As program's author Igor Pavlov [explains](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/448b560f), the following happens when Windows Photo Viewer is set as default image viewer in Windows:

> The Program1 (some photo file handler) calls another Program2 (windows photo viewer) and closes Program1. 
>   But 7-Zip waits only Program1. So it deletes image from temp folder.
>   I plan to fix that problem in future.

The problem still exists in latest stable 7-Zip 9.20, though I didn't check if it is fixed in latest alpha.

There is a not-so-difficult workaround: use alternative image viewer as your default one. Personally, I use [FastStone](http://www.faststone.org/), but [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/) etc. should be fine too.

Comment: It's already fixed

Answer (score 1):

7-Zip may just be storing files temporarily in a location that is hidden to the image viewers, or outside of their security context.

You'd have to use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from SysInternals to see exactly where the file is being saved when you double-click on it, to see why Photo Viewer isn't seeing it.

This is even more relevant on Vista and Windows 7, with its enhanced security mode.

Have you tried running 7-Zip as Administrator, to see if that "fixes" the problem?

Comment: I use to open archives by dblclicking and not sure how to launch 7-ZIP in "admin" mode from popup menu...

Comment: Open Z-Zip normally with Admin mode (from a shortcut in the Start Menu or whatever), open a compressed file in the 7-Zip file browser, and then double-click on an image within that file.

Comment: This will never work. I tried everything, too. It seems 7-Zip deletes the files too fast (does not detect a lock on the file..)

Comment: Then I guess the moral of the story is, extract if you want to view it.

Comment: Or you should use non-default picture viewer that works smoothly with 7-zip.

Comment: Can you recommend one, FoxyBOA?